# How to fix the style of ASP.NET AjaxToolkit ComboBox?

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to use ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit. I like the ComboBox control and I am trying to use it as (it is) in [its website HERE](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx).

I just dragged and dropped it in my simple page and I applied the style to it. However, it did not display properly as in its website.

**ASP.NET Code:**

```
<div>
        <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
                            AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="AjaxToolkitStyle" AppendDataBoundItems="false">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ComboBox>
    </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body, div, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, ul, li, table
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
}
/* ComboBox styles */
#master_content .ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    margin: 0px;
}

.AjaxToolkitStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input
{
    background-image: url(ComboBox/images/toolkit-bg.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    border: 0px none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px 0px 3px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 240px;
}
.AjaxToolkitStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
{
    background-image: url(ComboBox/images/toolkit-arrow.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    border: 0px none;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
}
.AjaxToolkitStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    border-color: #0F2543;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

Here's snapshot of what I have:

[image]

So **how can I fix this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
position: relative;
top: -7px;
```

in `.AjaxToolkitStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input`

Adjust the top accordingly